how to return JSON response instead of HTML from spring boot based API
I have a simple app created using spring boot version 2.7.18 and uses spring security as well. Below is WebSecurityConfig class:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.ldapAuthentication()
        .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=users")
        .contextSource(contextSource())
        .passwordCompare()
        .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
  }

  @Bean
  public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource() {
    return new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=example,dc=com");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors()
        .configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues())
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
        .permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/actuator/**")
        .permitAll() // Adjust permissions as needed
        .antMatchers("/v1/createUser/**")
        .permitAll() // Exclude /v1/user endpoint from authentication
        .antMatchers("/v1/login/**")
        .permitAll() // Exclude /v1/create endpoint from authentication
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin();
  }
}

Below is a controller method:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class UserController {
@GetMapping(value = "/user", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<User> getUserByUsername(
      @RequestParam String username,
      @RequestHeader(AuthenticationControllerConstants.AUTHORIZATION_NAME)
          String authorizationToken) {
    if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(authorizationToken)) {
      User user = userService.findByUsername(username);
      if (user != null) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(user);
      } else {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
      }
    } else {
      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body(null);
    }
  }
}

The application is using docker and I run the application using docker compose up command.
The issue is that when I run test through Postman , it always returns response in html format. Below is the example of the response when I send request to endpont - http://localhost:8080/v1/user:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Please sign in</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/signin/signin.css" rel="stylesheet"
        crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-signin" method="post" action="/login">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
            <p>
                <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
            </p>
            <input name="_csrf" type="hidden" value="407f9921-a9ee-46b4-bab7-6f50a4fb735f" />
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>

Basically, I want the response in JSON and so I even added produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE to the controller method, but that doesn't solve the issue. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Did you provided a valid login information like username and password from postman while calling the API endpoint? This html page is returned by spring security if the user is not signed in and you are trying to fetch a protected endpoint.

This is not the problem about return type. The html you saw is what Spring return as default (without needing any config). This tell you that you didn't login so that first of all login with the html login page first. In case if you want to turn this login off, you .permitAll

I have this configuration - antMatchers("/v1/createUser/**").permitAll() in my WebSecurityConfig class, but still for endpoint /v1/createUser/ I am getting the html response.In this case, shouldn't it permit for /v1/createUser/ endpoint?

you right, this should work, if you still getting error, try to run debug or turn on trace log
